# Which of the following system calls behave same for both blocking and non-blocking sockets?

Tags: sockets, blocking, system-calls, nonblocking

Hi can any one tell me which of the calls behave same for both blocking and non blocking sockets:

receive and send
accept
connect

Comment: Why can't you tell from the documentation? It's perfectly clear.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `receive` call - I think you mean `recv`. From the manual pages you can tell that none of the calls behaves the same in blocking vs. non-blocking mode.